# Question about $L^1$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Someone told me that "$L^1$ functions have to decay to 0 at $\pm\infty$."
I know that the $L^1$ function is defined as a collection of functions such that $\int_{X}|f|dx<\infty$ where $X$ is an arbitrary set.Can someone explain me the meaning of decay to 0?

Answer (score 1):

A function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ does not necessarily decay in the sense that
$$
\lim_{|x| \to \infty}f(x)=0,
$$
but for every $\epsilon>0$ you can find a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K}|f|dx<\epsilon.
$$
By chosing a ball $B_R(0)$ around $0$ such that $K \subset B_R(0)$, you know that your function is concetrated in that ball and has "negligible integral mass" outside that ball.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. $L^p$ functions need not converge **point-wise** to zero. Try yourself to come up with an example of an $L^1$ function $f$ without $\lim_{x→∞}f(x)=0$.
2. $L^p$ functions converge to zero **on average**: let $I$ be any compact interval (*), then the average absolute function value on that interval goes to zero, as we shift the interval towards infinity:

$$\lim_{a→∞} \frac{1}{|I|}∫_{I+a} |f(x)|^p dx = 0$$

(*) with non-empty interior, i.e. we exclude intervals consisting only of a single point.